# XSLT - Sort xml parent segments based on child tag

Tags: sorting, xslt

My need is to sort xml segments based on a child tag value, eventhough the parent tags can have different names.

My input xml is like this

```
<root>
  <A>
    <id>1000</id>
  </A>
  <A>
     <id>1001</id>
  </A>
  <A>
    <id>1002</id>
  </A>

  <B>
    <id>1000</id>
  </B>
  <B>
    <id>1001</id>
  </B>
  <B>
    <id>1002</id>
  </B>
</root>
```

I want the sort done on the tag 'id' no matter what the parent tag is. So the result should look like this:

```
 <root>
    <A>
       <id>1000</id>
    </A>
    <B>
       <id>1000</id>
    </B>

    <A>
       <id>1001</id>
    </A>
    <B>
       <id>1001</id>
    </B>

    <A>
       <id>1002</id>
    </A>
    <B>
       <id>1002</id>
    </B>
  </root>
```

How do I achieve that in xslt?

Thanks!
Tom

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow, this is not a coding service and problem exposed must come with the code you wrote to solve the problem, please read [ask] to get a better idea how to ask a proper question

Answer (score 1):

The template matching `root` should contain `apply-templates`
with `select="*"` (for all child nodes) and with `<xsl:sort select="id"/>`
inside.

So the whole XSLT script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="id"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I used `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to achieve
"better" output formatting. Try transformation without it to see
the difference.